# Grails setting locale does not change language

Tags: grails, internationalization, locale, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.0.3 in my project. I would like to implement internationalization to my application. As far as I read from [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/i18n.html) documentation I understand Grails have an out box support for internationalization. However I would like to override browsers `Accept-Header` setting and would like to set users language preference.

First I've created a filter in order to catch requests and check the language preferences. But it did not help. In filter I can get localized messages but when page is rendered I am getting English page. Here is the code that I use for setting locale.

```
def locale = new Locale("es", "ES")
java.util.Locale.setDefault(locale)
```

Then I've created custom `LocaleResolver` and injected that in spring configuration as `localeResolver`. Again in filter I can see localized messages however in pages still no luck?

Is there a way to override or bypass browsers setting in Grails i18n support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `LocaleResolver` of Grails is `SessionLocaleResolver`. If you want to always use `es_ES` you can change this to `FixedLocaleResolver`.

```
beans {
  localeResolver(FixedLocaleResolver) {
    locale = new Locale("es", "ES")
  }
}
```

If you want to restrict to a set of locales, then you will need a filter, and use the `SessionLocaleResolver#setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale)` method.

Comment: Michels Thanks for you answer. I just wonder why lang=es is not working in my application? i18n works only if I change browser settings. Is there a config issue in my application?

Comment: lang=xxx don't work when you don't have a controller for that view. I think there's a JIRA ticket for this. If you create a controller with an index action and change lang it should work.

Comment: All my actions go through a controller. So I have controller. this is very weird as in my filter I can read internationalised message however when page is rendered it is still in English.

Comment: Can you update your question with your filter, and also a example of view that don't show the correct locale messages?

Comment: Hi Sergio thanks for you help much appreciated. The issue was somehow that view does not touch a controller and I fixed that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer , but want to point out in spring mvc version 4.0 , the FixedLocaleResolver does not have mutable locale field , it has defaultLocale as mutable field so the beans config should be something like this ```localeResolver(FixedLocaleResolver) {
        defaultLocale = new Locale("en", "US")
    } ```